# Mongo Flux/Mono add element after verification

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm new with web flux and mongo react. The most tuto explain the basic of the use this two technologie -_-.

I'm already want to add a beneficiary Object into collection Benefeciary and user Object into User collection, but before I have to verify the unicity of this two object. I have a **list**(ArrayList), where I add to it the raise exception. If any this **list** not empty I'll throw a RuntimeExeption (I manage that with WebExceptionHandler) with all the raised exception

My question is how to block the call to the db until and verify that all data it's ok? (how waiting for the processing to finish)

```
    //Function used to detect if I had any error with the DTO object 
    Mono<Beneficiary> detectFunctionalError(CreateBeneficiaryRequestDTO requestDTO) {

            return beneficiaryRepository.findBeneficiariesByName(requestDTO.getBeneficiaryName()).log().doOnSuccessOrError((data, errors)->{
                if(data!=null){
                    functionalExceptionHandler.appendException(O2CCodeError.O2C003);
                    LOGGER.error(O2CCodeError.O2C003.getCode() + ":" + O2CCodeError.O2C003.getDescription() + ":" + O2CCodeError.O2C003.getSource()
                            + ":" + O2CCodeError.O2C003.getType());
                }
                userService.findUserByEmail(requestDTO.getBeneficiaryEmail()).log().doOnSuccessOrError((userData, exceptions)->{
                    if (userData!=null){
                        functionalExceptionHandler.appendException(O2CCodeError.O2C004);
                        LOGGER.error(O2CCodeError.O2C004.getCode()+":"+O2CCodeError.O2C004.getDescription()+":"+O2CCodeError.O2C004.getSource()
                                +":"+O2CCodeError.O2C004.getType());
                    }

//this call responsable to call RuntimeExeption
                    functionalExceptionHandler.checkExceptions();
                    //Mono.empty();
                });
            });

    }



    public Mono<Beneficiary> addBeneficiary(CreateBeneficiaryRequestDTO requestDTO) {

        this.detectFunctionalError(requestDTO);
      //continue the save...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you something like this:

```
Mono<Beneficiary> found = beneficiaryRepository.findBeneficiariesByName(requestDTO.getBeneficiaryName());

return found.flatMap(beneficiary-> {
            if(beneficiary== null)
                return Mono.empty(); // never called
            else
                return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Already exist " + beneficiary.getId()));

        }).switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(requestDTO.getBeneficiaryObjectToSave())); // new object here which want to save.
```

Comment: here you manage only the benefeciary, but the problem for me is to manage a beneficiary and user, in other word a list of db call. And after each one I added the custom error. I hope that clear

Answer (score 0):

**1)**
Checking for null is not correct! [Reactor API is null safety](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#kotlin-null-safety)!

If you find some results *Spring Data* emits the found values otherwise returns empty `Flux/Mono`.

Collect your errors like that:

```
beneficiaryRepository.findBeneficiariesByName(requestDTO.getBeneficiaryName())
    .log()
    .doOnNext(data -> functionalExceptionHandler.appendException(O2CCodeError.O2C003))
    ...
    .doOnNext(userData -> functionalExceptionHandler.appendException(O2CCodeError.O2C004);)
```

***2)***
Combine your publishers and call checking operator in the one chain.

```
 return beneficiaryRepository.findBeneficiariesByName(requestDTO.getBeneficiaryName())
    .doOnNext(... //collect errors)
    .compose(flux -> userService.findUserByEmail(requestDTO.getBeneficiaryEmail())
        .doOnNext(...//collect errors)
    )
    .then(Mono.defer(() -> functionalExceptionHandler.checkExceptions() ? Mono.empty() : Mono.error(RuntimeException::new)));
```

thereafter

```
public Mono<Beneficiary> addBeneficiary(CreateBeneficiaryRequestDTO requestDTO) {

    this.detectFunctionalError(requestDTO)
        .switchIfEmpty(// your save logic)
```

if error occurs emitting will be stopped otherwise switch to your save logic

Comment: I have the bellow Error:

concatWith (org.reactivestreams.Publisher<? extend com.berg.Beneficiary>) is Mono cannot be applied to (reactor.core.publisher.Mono<com.berg.User>)